# Send email to recipient based on date

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-sheets, automation

I currently have this script for a Google Sheets file I'm working on:

```
function myAlerts() { // this runs based on daily trigger
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Reminders");
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();   var values = range.getDisplayValues();
  var lastRow = range.getLastRow();

  var curDate = values[1][5]

  var anyMatches = false;
  var message = "";   var sheetUrl = ss.getUrl();
  var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var optionalEmail = values[2][1]; 
  if (optionalEmail != "") { email = email + "," + optionalEmail; }
  for (var i = 5; i < lastRow; i++) {
    // if today matches the alert date, send an alert
    if (values[i][3].toString() == curDate.toString()) {  
      // add a message for this row if date matches
      message = message + values[i][0] + " will expire on " + values[i][1] + "<br />\n";

      // if there is a match, set anyMatches to true so and email gets sent
      anyMatches = true;
    }
  }  // ends for loop
  // footer for message
  message = message +  "<br />\nThis is an auto-generated email to remind you of your document expiration. <br />\n"
  if (anyMatches)  { // send an email   
      MailApp.sendEmail({
        to: email,
        subject: 'Document Expiration Notice!',
        htmlBody: message});
  }
}
```

In my sheet, the script sends an email to me (owner of the sheet) and an additional person if I enter an email address in B3. The script looks at F2, and checks column D to see if any dates match. If they do it sends an email with information from the other columns, in that same row.

How can I edit this script so that it will not only send the email to me, and the email address in B3, but ALSO the email address in that same row, which has a matching date??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove your `{ email = email + "," + optionalEmail;}` from the first `if` statement, and move it after the second, adding the email value just like you did for the `optionalEmail` variable.

```
  if (values[i][3].toString() == curDate.toString())    {  
          email = email + "," + optionalEmail + "," + values[i][2];
```

UPDATE for comment:

Valid point that I didn't catch when I made the change suggestion.  That requires a little more work.  You need to move the whole `MailApp.sendEmail` chunk into the second `if` statement.  Then you need to 'clear' your variables each iteration so that they don't carry over into the next iteration.  To do this effectively, you will need to create a new variable to hold the email recipients (`recip`).  The code will throw an error if you clear the `email` variable, because of the logic you are using to populate it.

Here is the updated code:

```
function myAlerts() { // this runs based on daily trigger   
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();   
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Reminders");
     var range = sheet.getDataRange();   var values = range.getDisplayValues();
     var lastRow = range.getLastRow();

  var curDate = values[1][5]

 var message = "";   var sheetUrl = ss.getUrl();
 var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();     var optionalEmail = values[2][1];  
    for (var i = 5; i < lastRow; i++)     {      // if today matches the alert date, send an alert
   if (values[i][3].toString() == curDate.toString())    {  
    var recip = email + "," + optionalEmail + "," + values[i][2]; 
         //changed variable to allow for clearing.
 // add a message for this row if date matches
     message = message + values[i][0] + " will expire on " + values[i][1] + "<br />\n";
     MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: recip,
      subject: 'Document Expiration Notice!',
      htmlBody: message});  
  recip = ""; // clears email recipients for next iteration.
  message = "";  // clears message for next iteration.
 }    

} // ends for loop

}  
     // footer for message   message = message +  "<br />\nThis is an auto-generated email to remind you of your document expiration. <br />\n"
```

I also removed the `anyMatches` variable, and the first `if` statement, because they aren't really needed for this to work.

Let me know if it still doesn't do what you need.

Comment: Thanks Ron, this does everything I want it to do perfectly. Cheers!